# How to convert VW to px in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, viewport-units

I can't figure out how i can easily convert a **vw** value into px to use it later on in my scss document.

Thanks!

Comment: First off, is there a specific reason you'd want to do that? I don't think it's possible to do that in pure CSS because view width values are relative to the window size, i.e. the ration from vw to px changes depending on the viewport's size.

Comment: @FallenWarrior I want to dynamically change the value of background-position based on the screen width. I need it to change exponentially, so i'm using [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/power-function/) Sass function to achieve that. Problem is, this function accepts only stripped values, so i need to somehow get the screen width in px and use it in this function.

Comment: Well, for that you will need to use some Javascript. The Sass engine, first of all, is server-side (and usually used in advance), so it doesn't know anything about actual screen sizes or that stuff anyways. As all Sass calculations need to be performed during compilation, you thus cannot use them to calculate what you want based on runtime values. I'd suggest you'd take a look at dynamically changing the CSS via JS.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that via SASS, because the output needs to be 'vw' if you want it to be based on the viewport. In order to get the viewport's pixel width, you'll have to use JavaScript.